# Python and OpenCV - How can I understand this bitwise operator?

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-and

I am a still beginner in programming, pordon me if this question is too trivial. Let say I have this code:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture('path_to_video_file')
while True:
    #reading frames of video
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

So, from my understanding, at the instance when the frame is shown (in the "Video" window), if at the same time, the `q` key is pressed, the loop would break. But I don't really understand how the `if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')` line works.

I do know this is an `AND` bitwise operation in which output is 1 only if both of the two inputs is also 1. But that is all abut it. So, I really want to know what is exactly happening.

And also, what is actually the `0xFF == ord('q')` means?

Comment: DIfferent OS will have different return values for `waitKey`, but the 2 LSB will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Python operator precedence gives us:

```
(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q')
```

In binary, this is:

```
(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0b11111111) == ord('q')
```

So, what this does is select the low 8 bits of the result `cv2.waitKey` and test if that's equal to `ord('q')`, which is the ASCII value for `'q'`.